# How to get first child URL within Craft/Twig Nav tags

Tags: navigation, forloop, loop, children

I have a navigation structure as follows:

```
{% set page = entry ?? category ?? null %}

<ul class="nav menu--main">
    {% nav entry in entries %}

        <li class="menu__item{% if page and page.id == entry.id %} is-current{% endif %}">

            <a {% if entry.type == 'noLink' %}href=""{% else %}href="{{ entry.url }}"{% endif %}>{{ entry.title }}</a>

            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul class="nav menu--submenu__wrapper">
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}

        </li>

    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

As you can see, I have an `entry.type` called "No link" which means that the user doesn't want the parent page to have a page of it's own, yet it still needs to appear in the nav to give context to the children.

My question is; how can I get the first child's URL within the `ifchildren` tags so I can make the parent automatically redirect to the first child's page in the navigation?

I know how to do this in regular forloops, but it would be nice to do this within Craft's `nav` tags.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you can put this in the `href` value:

```
{{ entry.descendants.type('page').first.url ?? '' }}
```

(Replace `page` with the other entry type handle(s).)